# How to use array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

How can I use `array_walk_recursive()` instead of this:

```
function check_value($val){
  if(is_array($val)){
    foreach($val as $key => $value)
      $val[$key] = check_value($value);
    return $val;
  }

  return clean_value($val);
}
```

?

Answer (score 8):

I think this should do the same thing. Note that argument of a function is passed as a reference (i.e. `&$value`).

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value) {
    $value = clean_value($value);
});
```

For older PHP versions:

```
function check_value(&$value) {
    $value = clean_value($value);
}
array_walk_recursive($array, 'check_value');
```

Comment: @BestDeveloper, Most likely your PHP version is too old. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the clean_value function to take a reference argument. 
For example, these two snippets are functionally identical:

1:

```
function clean_value($value) {
    //manipulate $value
    return $value;
}

$value = clean_value($value);
```

and

2:

```
function clean_value(&$value) {
    //manipulate $value
}

clean_value($value);
```

For the latter (2), we can use it in array_walk_recursive as follows:

```
array_walk_recursive($value_tree, 'clean_value');
```

If we can't edit clean_value, I would solve it as follows:

```
$clean_by_reference = function(&$val) {
    $val = clean_value($val);
};
array_walk_recursive($value_tree, $clean_by_reference);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function check_value ( $val ) {
    if ( is_array ( $val ) ) array_walk_recursive ( $val, 'check_value' );
    return clean_value ( $val );
}
```