# Find latest children in nested categories php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried to parse a JSON using PHP from url. I need a list of item that have no children - means `children` field should be empty array and `parent_id` shouldn't be `0` - means not be parents.

JSON:

```
{
  "body": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "car",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bmw",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "bmw i8",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "mustang",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "clothes",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "mobile",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "apple",
            "parent_id": "6",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Iphone 12 pro",
                "parent_id": "7",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Iphone 11",
                "parent_id": "7",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Xiaomi",
            "parent_id": "6",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output Expected:

```
[4,3,9,10,8]
```

This is my php code that i tried and doesn't work.

```
    $CategoryUrl = file_get_contents(self::CATEGORY_URL,true);
    $array = json_decode($CategoryUrl,true);
    $list = array();
    foreach( $array['body']['data'] as $value ){
        if (($value['parent_id'] != 0) && empty($value['children'])) { 
            foreach( $value['children'] as $val ){
                    $list[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($list);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use array\_walk\_recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547775/how-to-use-array-walk-recursive)

Comment: It's somewhat similar but it didn't help me. @nice_dev

Comment: It provides the general mechanism - a recursive walk over the entire array is exactly what you need. You just have to tinker with the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a little tricky to keep track of parent ID values and children call using `array_walk_recursive` as it jumps directly to its children. However, this can be still accomplished with your own recursive version like below. Keep checking with `parent_id` and `children` count. If both constraints satisfy, add them to `$result`, else keep calling `children` recursively.

```
<?php

$str = '{"body":{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"car","parent_id":"0","children":[{"id":2,"name":"bmw","parent_id":"1","children":[{"id":4,"name":"bmw i8","parent_id":"2","children":[]}]},{"id":3,"name":"mustang","parent_id":"1","children":[]}]},{"id":5,"name":"clothes","parent_id":"0","children":[]},{"id":6,"name":"mobile","parent_id":"0","children":[{"id":7,"name":"apple","parent_id":"6","children":[{"id":9,"name":"Iphone 12 pro","parent_id":"7","children":[]},{"id":10,"name":"Iphone 11","parent_id":"7","children":[]}]},{"id":8,"name":"Xiaomi","parent_id":"6","children":[]}]}]}}';


$data = json_decode($str,true);
$result = [];


function walkRecursive($data,&$result){
    foreach($data as $entry){
        if($entry['parent_id'] != 0 && count($entry['children']) == 0){
            $result[] = $entry['id'];
        }else{
            walkRecursive($entry['children'],$result);
        }
    }
}

walkRecursive($data['body']['data'],$result);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem by **function call recursive algorithm,**
hope it clear for you

```
$CategoryUrl = file_get_contents(self::CATEGORY_URL,true);
$array = json_decode($CategoryUrl, true);
$items = $array['body']['data'];
$list = [];

findParentIds(items, $list);

// doSomething 

print_r($list);


/**
 * passe by ref (list)
 * @param array $children
 * @param $list
 */
function findParentIds(array $children, & $list)
{
    foreach ($children as $child) {

        // use case 1: has no children and parent_id is 0 , just continue
        if (empty($child['children']) && $child['parent_id'] == "0") {
            continue;
        }
        // use case 2: has no children and parent_id is 0 , it's parent item
        if (empty($child['children']) && $child['parent_id'] != "0") {
            array_push($list, $child['id']);

        }

        // has children and parent_id is not 0 , recall function to treat use case 1 and 2 ..
        findParentIds($child['children'], $list);
    }
}
```